# Deleting integers that are sandwiched between symbols

Tags: list-manipulation, pattern-matching, filtering

I have a list of symbols and integers:

```
 lis  = {a, b, c, 1, d, e, 2, 3, f}
```

I'd like to delete each integer that is preceded and succeeded by a symbol:

```
  res = {a, b, c, d, e, 2, 3, f}

SequenceCases[lis, {a__Symbol, _Integer, b__Symbol} -> {a, b}]
```

...gives

```
{{a, b, c, d, e}}
```

Comment: Take a look at `SequenceReplace`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
Flatten[DeleteCases[SplitBy[lis, IntegerQ], {_Integer}]]
SequenceReplace[lis, {a_Symbol, _Integer, b_Symbol} -> Sequence[a, b]]
With[{s = ArrayPad[BlockMap[FreeQ[#, {_Symbol, _Integer, _Symbol}]&, lis, 3, 1], 1, True]}
  Pick[lis,s]]
```

all give

> {a, b, c, d, e, 2, 3, f}

Comment: Yes, I missed the Sequence[a,b] in the second solution.  Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

[`ListCorrelate`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ListCorrelate.html) can be useful.

```
lis = {a, b, c, 1, d, e, 2, 3, f};

bin = Boole[IntegerQ /@ lis]

Pick[lis, Unitize[ListCorrelate[{1, 2, 4}, bin, 2] - 2], 1]
```

> ```
> {0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0}
>
> {a, b, c, d, e, 2, 3, f}
> ```

This is faster than either of the methods in kglr's answer that I am able to test in version 10.1:

```
lis = RandomChoice[{a, b, c, 1, d, e, 2, 3, f}, 150000];

With[{bin = Boole[IntegerQ /@ lis]}, 
   Pick[lis, Unitize[ListCorrelate[{1, 2, 4}, bin, 2] - 2], 1]] // 
  Length // RepeatedTiming

Flatten[DeleteCases[SplitBy[lis, IntegerQ], {_Integer}]] // Length // RepeatedTiming

With[{s = ArrayPad[BlockMap[FreeQ[#, {_Symbol, _Integer, _Symbol}] &, lis, 3, 1], 1,
       True]}, Pick[lis, s]] // Length // RepeatedTiming
```

> ```
> {0.0556, 127770}
>
> {0.136, 127770}
>
> {0.1642, 127770}
> ```

Most of the time is spent on binarizing the list, so with a faster form for that:

```
With[{bin = Replace[lis, {_Integer -> 1, _ -> 0}, {1}]}, 
   Pick[lis, Unitize[ListCorrelate[{1, 2, 4}, bin, 2] - 2], 1]] // 
  Length // RepeatedTiming
```

> ```
>  {0.0219, 127770}
> ```

Answer (score 2):

```
list = {a, b, c, 1, d, e, 2, 3, f, 9, g};
```

Using `SequenceSplit` (new in 11.3)

```
SequenceSplit[list, {a_Symbol, _Integer, b_Symbol} :> {a, b}] // Flatten
```

{a, b, c, d, e, 2, 3, f, g}

Using `SequencePosition` (new in 10.1)

```
SequencePosition[list, {a_Symbol, _Integer, _Symbol}] /. {a_Integer, _} :> {a}
```

{{3}, {9}}

```
Delete[%] @ list
```

{a, b, 1, d, e, 2, 3, 9, g}

Answer (score 1):

```
lis = {a, b, c, 1, d, e, 2, 3, f, 5, h};
```

Using `ReplaceRepeated`:

```
lis //. {a___, b_Symbol, n_Integer , c_Symbol, d___} :> {a, b, c, d}

(*{a, b, c, d, e, 2, 3, f, h}*)
```

Or using `SequenceCases` and `DeleteElements`:

```
DeleteElements[#, SequenceCases[#, {a_Symbol, n_Integer, b_Symbol} :> n]] &@lis

(*{a, b, c, d, e, 2, 3, f, h}*)
```